# JavaFX WebView doesn't execute JavaScript

Tags: webview, javafx

I am on Windows 8. I have a JavaFX app that creates a simple window with a webview control and loads the local file "test.html". "test.html" contains javascript (a simple "alert("hello");<(script>"). 
However, the javascript is ignored. 
What rendering engine does webview in JavaFX use? 
I have Firefox and IE installed. The latter executes JS contained in local files only if the users accepts to do so. So my assumption is that webview uses IE due to some configuration of my OS. Is this possible? 
Thanks for your help.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class Hello extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(browser);

        String filepath = this.getClass().getResource("test.html").toExternalForm();

        webEngine.load(filepath);


        scene.setRoot(scrollPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaFX WebView does not visually show a popup when you use the alert() function in javascript. Instead it raises an event in java that you can handle like this:

```
myWebView.getEngine().setOnAlert((WebEvent<String> wEvent) -> {
  System.out.println("JS alert() message: " + wEvent.getData() );
});
```